# How do I link directly to my ebook in the iBookstore?

Tags: ibooks

I know we can link to our apps via http://itunes.com/apps/developername or http://itunes.com/apps/appname, but how do we link to our ebook in the iBooks part of iTunes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find your book ID in your iTunes Connect account if you published it yourself in your bookshelf at http://itunesconnect.apple.com

If you didn't publish it, you can find your book ID with:

https://selfpublish.org/ibooks.md

Just be sure to edit the URL so it follows this convention:

https://books.apple.com/us/book/id397839902

I posted a more detailed tutorial awhile back. When I find it, I'll add a link to it.

Comment: Perfect. In my hybrid iOS app, this links directly to the book in iBooks, whereas the link created by iTunes Link Maker opens up my browser and then loads iBooks.